# How can we set NGINX web server and its RTMP module on mac system?

Tags: macos, nginx, rtmp

How can we set NGINX web server and its RTMP module on mac system?

I have tried to set up server using below link

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Getting-started-with-nginx-rtmp

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Installing-via-Build

But could not run it as it give error as below :-

```
nginx-rtmp-module-master XXXXX$ ./configure --add-module=/path/to/nginx-rtmp-module --with-debug ...
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `./configure: No such file or directory`... You're just missing that file...

Comment: you can try something like this                                                                 
brew tap homebrew/nginx
brew install nginx-full --with-rtmp-module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try these, I used the same method to install `auth_module` on my mac.

1. `brew tap homebrew/nginx`
2. `brew install nginx-full --with-rtmp-module --with-debug`

Comment: The `homebrew/nginx` tap has been deprecated, and is now empty. This answer is not currently valid.

Answer (score 24):

I've faced the same problem, however `brew tap homebrew/nginx` returns a error

> Error: homebrew/nginx was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its
>   formulae were migrated.

I solved it with

`brew tap denji/homebrew-nginx`

Instead of

`brew tap homebrew/homebrew-nginx`

Answer (score 0):

reinstall

```
brew remove nginx
brew install nginx-full --with-rtmp-module --with-debug
```